# How can I bring a view in front of another view, in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder

Below are how my views are organized in IB, top->bottom when the app is started.

The user can do something to make "Category Table View Header" temporarily expand over "Name View" - however once doing so, the .TouchDown action assigned to "Category Table View Header" no longer works wherever it overlaps with "Name View" (i.e., the user can tap the header anywhere it doesn't overlap with name view and it still works).

[image]

I know that may be confusing, so I drew out some boxes. On the left is the original, right is after user action - problem is on the right the action on the red box only works if the user taps the bottom half, not the top half.

[image]

My guess is its because the header is lower in the view hierarchy than the name view, but it would be hard for me to change that without messing around with a bunch of constraints.

I also tried setting nameView.hidden = true, but that doesn't work.

Comment: it shouldnt mess with your constraints moving it around in the view hierarchy, so long as it stays at the same level, put your `Name View` below your `Choose Quote View` (not in it) and it should work

Comment: Hey Fonix - thanks for the suggestion, but that seems to only make the view "appear" in front of the one below it in the view hierarchy. The actions associated with that view do not. In other words, I still run into the problem faced by the boxes I drew in my original question - the action doesn't work in the "overlap area".

Comment: I think I figured it out - you can't move a view's child in front of that same view's sibling. I fixed it by "upgrading" the view's child to be its sibling, then moving it to the front.

Answer (score 81):

**If you want to bring a subview to the front, you can use:**

**SWIFT 4 + UPDATE**

```
self.view.bringSubviewToFront(yourView)
```

**SWIFT 3 UPDATE**

```
self.view.bringSubview(toFront: yourView)
```

**Send view to back:-**

**SWIFT 4+ UPDATE**

```
self.view.sendSubviewToBack(yourView)
```

**SWIFT 3 UPDATE**

```
self.view.sendSubview(toBack: yourView)
```

**SWIFT 4+ UPDATE - INSERT VIEW ON SPECIFIC LOCATION IN THE STACK**

```
 parentView.insertSubview(yourView, belowSubview: requiredViewOnStack)
 parentView.insertSubview(yourView, aboveSubview: requiredViewOnStack)
```

Comment: That didn't work for me - the actions associated with the view moved to the front do not, also, "move to the front" In other words, I still run into the problem faced by the boxes I drew in my original question - the action doesn't work in the "overlap area". Maybe the title of this question is misleading as it suggests the solution involves reordering, when there is actually a different solution.

Answer (score 10):

In **Swift 5**

To bring a subview to front

```
self.view.bringSubviewToFront(yourView)
```

To send a subview to back

```
self.view.sendSubviewToBack(yourView)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can take a control over the order of subviews using methods: bringSubviewToFront and sendSubviewToBack from the superview.

You can access all the subviews contained by superview using self.view.subview array.

Comment: Thanks, Tosha - that didn't work for me - the actions associated with the view moved to the front do not, also, "move to the front" In other words, I still run into the problem faced by the boxes I drew in my original question - the action doesn't work in the "overlap area". Maybe the title of this question is misleading as it suggests the solution involves reordering, when there is actually a different solution.

Comment: I see. Please, tell me first - how did you actually associated action with the view (button, or tap gesture..,) ??

Comment: Hey tosha - I think I figured it out, as mentioned in my comment above. I needed to upgrade my view from child to sibling.

Answer (score 1):

**The method has been updated since swift 3**

What has worked for me and hopefully for you is using :

```
YourView.bringSubview(toFront: yourelementA)
YourView.bringSubview(toFront: yourelementB)
```

Alternatively you could use the following to send the object that is in the front:

```
YourView.sendSubview(toBack: yourelementC)
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5.4**

views in UIKit are drawn from the back towards the front (like adding icing onto a cake). This means that the new views will be placed **on top/over** the previously placed views. (e.g. Icing is the **new** view and the base of the cake being the **old** view.

You can use the following to manipulate the views Z-position using,

1. Forward

```
parent.bringSubviewToFront(child)
```

2. Backward

```
parent.sendSubviewToBack(child)
```

Answer (score -1):

bringSubViewToFront did not work in my case, Take a look

[image]

As I wanted this notification count comes before image, bringSubViewToFront did not work, So I just drag this label below to stack view of my imgae and bottom label, it worked for me.
I hope this will work for all