# How to control depth in UIKit?

Tags: swift, autolayout, uikit

I am having an issue with the "depth" of views in UIKit. The ImageView is on top of the TextField, but I want the converse: the text field on top. Below goes an image showing the problem:

[image]

FWIW: In SwiftUI, there is ZStack which allows one to easily define what goes on top of what, but I am looking for a solution in UIKit as this project is for a course I am doing to learn UIKit.

The project is on GitHub and is called [MemeEditor](https://github.com/ataias/MemeEditor/tree/e2a25a62c5485b83137fe7ed280e845f64066c1c). This link goes to a commit that presents the aforementioned problem.

Thanks!

Comment: In UIKit the z-index is specified simply by the order of the views in their superview, therefore just move the stackview with the image to be the first subview.

Answer (score 1):

> I am looking for a solution in UIKit as this project is for a course I am doing to learn UIKit.

From your question, it sounds like you're looking for a way to do this in code. UIView contains a number of methods that let you change the z-order of subviews, such as `insertSubview(_:aboveSubview:)` and `insertSubview(_:belowSubview:)`, but since you already have two existing subviews you can use [`exchangeSubview(at:withSubviewAt:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622448-exchangesubview) to just swap the positions of the text view and image in the `subviews` array.

Comment: I didn't know about ` exchangeSubview(at:withSubviewAt:)`, nice one! I didn't intend to look for a way to do this in code... it is just that I had looked around in the storyboard and assumed wrongly it was too hard (newbie days in uikit, or maybe it is just counter-intuitive in the beginning?)

Answer (score 0):

I actually found two solutions:

## Code Solution

From:
[How can I bring a view in front of another view, in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38780743/how-can-i-bring-a-view-in-front-of-another-view-in-swift)

With that, I had to add to the View Controller the line

```
self.view.bringSubviewToFront(textField)
```

[Diff here](https://github.com/ataias/MemeEditor/commit/eba43a4b3962882bc0e0b66630948966af81dad6)

## Storyboard solution

After a few days, I got feedback on the project and I understood how to do this in the storyboard. Views will show on top when they after down in the hierarchy on the storyboard.

So, I changed from:

[image: wrong hiearchy]

to:

[image: correct hierarchy]

and the code worked. FWIW the diff is:

```
diff --git a/MemeEditor/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard b/MemeEditor/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard
index c4fbb55..18400ce 100644
--- a/MemeEditor/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard
+++ b/MemeEditor/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard
@@ -16,6 +16,14 @@
                         <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="414" height="896"/>
                         <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                         <subviews>
+                            <stackView opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" axis="vertical" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="l0u-Hb-3mT">
+                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="44" width="414" height="818"/>
+                                <subviews>
+                                    <imageView clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFit" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="JJT-iB-9fc">
+                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="414" height="818"/>
+                                    </imageView>
+                                </subviews>
+                            </stackView>
                             <textField contentMode="center" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" placeholder="TOP MESSAGE" textAlignment="center" minimumFontSize="17" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="cOM-zN-T9a" userLabel="Top Text Field">
                                 <rect key="frame" x="10" y="84" width="394" height="49.5"/>
                                 <color key="textColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
@@ -28,14 +36,6 @@
                                 <fontDescription key="fontDescription" name="HelveticaNeue-CondensedBlack" family="Helvetica Neue" pointSize="40"/>
                                 <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits" autocapitalizationType="allCharacters"/>
                             </textField>
-                            <stackView opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" axis="vertical" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="l0u-Hb-3mT">
-                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="44" width="414" height="818"/>
-                                <subviews>
-                                    <imageView clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFit" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="JJT-iB-9fc">
-                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="414" height="818"/>
-                                    </imageView>
-                                </subviews>
-                            </stackView>
                             <toolbar opaque="NO" clearsContextBeforeDrawing="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="OY4-30-dsi">
                                 <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="813" width="414" height="49"/>
                                 <items>
```

Comment: If this solution worked in your case, great, but `bringSubviewToFront(_:)` is a pretty blunt instrument -- there will be times when you don't want to move the obscured subview all the way to the front.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out @Caleb ! I found out another solution so I updated the response to contain both.

Answer (score -2):

Copy the view you want to be front (⌘C), delete the old one and paste it (⌘V).

Comment: This is already the case, but it does not influence the order.

Comment: This answer was not well explained for a beginner in UIKit like me. After a few days I understood what change was needed in the story board. I need to make the text views appear after (down) in the storyboard hierarchy.